# POST Order with values for configurable product fields?

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I've successfully got 3rd party merchant orders posting new orders to my client's BigCommerce store programmatically. I've even got product options posting as part of the order (product->option set-> option relationships are a total cluster).

My client relies heavily on configurable fields.  I'm able to pull the definitions of the configurable fields for each product, but can't find a way to POST or update the configurable field values through the API.

**Is it possible to manipulate an order's configurable fields through the API?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a response from the support team @ BigCommerce. Manipulating configurable fields via the API is **not currently possible** and **not currently on the roadmap.**

Original reply below:

> Unfortunately that is a product limitation with the API, it will not tie to configurable fields on the product. The best you can do is attach that information through a generic text field like 'staff_notes'. Honestly I have not heard of any talk of adding a way to add products with configurable fields to orders via the API. I think this may be because anything that can be done with configurable fields can be done with options and options are what is being pushed for the future. I have noted this feedback down though and will pass it along to our Product Manager for the API. Best case scenario is that it may be seen in a future version of the API which is at least several months away.